# Problem with promise and @@iterator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, promise

I am new with the `Promise` object. When I run the code below in `NodeJS`

```
function solution(num){
    return getData(num).then(getMax); 
}

function getData(num){
    return Promise.resolve({
        first: 80 * num,
        second: 30 * num
    });
}

function getMax(numbers){
    return Promise.resolve(Math.max(...numbers));
}

solution(10)
```

I face the error

> (node:7814) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Found
>   non-callable @@iterator
>           at getMax

Could you help me to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: add `solution(10).catch(console.log)` and you'll see the problem

Comment: You really shouldn't be using promises here. Everything you do is synchronous.

Answer (score 8):

you are doing `...numbers` which expects `numbers` to be iterable , but in your case it is object

try making it an array ( or any iterable ) and it should work

```js
function solution(num){
    return getData(num).then(getMax); 
}


function getData(num){
    return Promise.resolve([80 * num, 30 * num]);
}

function getMax(numbers){
    return Promise.resolve(Math.max(...numbers));
}

solution(10).then(console.log)
```

please read this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995206/problem-when-implement-promise-in-javascript/61995238?noredirect=1#comment109647868_61995238) if you want to fix your original code

Comment: or without changing `getData`, you could do `...Object.values(numbers)`

Comment: Could you fix it without changing getData and getMax?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your iterator error by using a **generator** function. JavaScript Objects, unlike Arrays, Sets, and Maps to name a few, do not come with a `Symbol.iterator` property. Many built-in functions, including `Math.max` will recognize an iterator based on the `Symbol.iterator` property. You can convert an object to an iterator by using a generator of its values.

```js
function solution(num){
  return getData(num).then(getObjectValuesIterator).then(getMax);
}

function getObjectValuesIterator(obj){
  return (function*() {
    for (const key in obj) {
      yield obj[key]
    }
  })()
}

function getData(num){
    return Promise.resolve({
        first: 80 * num,
        second: 30 * num
    });
}

function getMax(numbers){
    return Promise.resolve(Math.max(...numbers));
}

solution(10).then(console.log) // => 800
```

`getObjectValuesIterator` returns an iterator based on a generator function. `Math.max` recognizes the iterator and does not error.

Answer (score 1):

You see the problem here is:

```
return getData(num).then(getMax);
```

In this case the successful callback from `getData` will return an object and you are passing that object into `getMax`.

The correct way here is:

```
return getData(num).then((result) => getMax(Object.values(result));
```